# Mysterious socket / HttpWebRequest timeouts

Tags: .net, sockets, httpwebrequest

I have a great app for capturing shoutcast streams :-) .  So far, it worked with a charm on dozens of machines, and never exhibited behaviour I found now, which is ultimately very strange.

I use HttpWebRequest to connect to different shoutcast servers and when I connect two streams, everything's OK.  When I go for third one,

```
   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

throws with Connection Timeout exception.

WTF?  I must point out that I had to create .config for the application in order to allow my headers to be sent out from the application, otherwise it wouldn't work at all.  Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.net>
    <settings>
    <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true" />
</settings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

Does any of this ring a bell?

Comment: I would like that same stream (third one, the one that timeouts) is perfectly playable with winamp.

Comment: I must point out that I am connecting to the completely different shoutcast servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this website has restriction on the number of simultaneous connections from the same ip address. Also take a look on

[ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx)

By default this value is 2. Change it to a bigger one.

Comment: You got it!  I have set it to 999 :) Do you know WHY it works on every other machine than this one?

Comment: I'm not sure but probably it's set to a another value in .NET configuration files on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ShoutCast server you're connecting to only allows two concurrent connections from the same machine? Or maybe your local settings are only allowing two concurrent outgoing connections?

Comment: I am connecting to multiple different shoutast servers.  And if my connections are limited to two PER PROCESS (check out my upper comment) then I would like where to change that setting (registry??!?)